# pgShapeLoader cannot be opened because of a problem

Tags: postgis, postgresql, boundless-suite

I installed the OpenGeo Suite 4.8 on MacOS 10.13. I can open pgadmin3 from the package, as well as PostGIS. When opening the pgShapeLoader I get the following error:

pgShapeLoader cannot be opened because of a problem.
Check with the developer to make sure pgShapeLoader works with this version of macOS. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and macOS.

> Process:               pgShapeLoader-bin [8517] Path:
>   /Applications/PostGIS
>   Utilities/pgShapeLoader.app/Contents/MacOS/pgShapeLoader Identifier:
>   org.opengeo.pgShapeLoader Version:               ??? Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:
>   pgShapeLoader-bin [8517] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2018-06-04 13:34:00.559 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   9D650379-9A83-3E81-917A-0F25D751B9FA
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       1F5D21D1-952B-4A1E-92BC-3CFBF24AC271
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds Time Since Wake:       1100
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing
>
> Application Specific Information: dyld: launch, loading dependent
>   libraries DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/PostGIS
>   Utilities/pgShapeLoader.app/Contents/Resources/lib
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not found: _inflateValidate   Referenced
>   from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
>   Expected in: /Applications/PostGIS
>   Utilities/pgShapeLoader.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libz.1.dylib  in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib

Does anybody understand what the error message is trying to tell me? Is there information in it that might help me to open pgShapeLoader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a particular problem of the OpenGeo Suite but a more general problem of MacOS Sierra and Hight Sierra with many other applications. The fundamental problem seems documented in this bug ([Incompatibility with libpng ≥ 1.6.26](https://github.com/Dead2/zlib-ng/issues/80))

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _inflateValidate
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
Expected in: ./libs/libz.1.dylib
```

The solution adopted for the other applications is to replace the (old) library in  pgShapeLoader.app (`/Applications/PostGIS Utilities/pgShapeLoader.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libz.1.dylib`)  by  another version (`/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (or /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib)`)

Comment: could you specify a little more what to replace with what from where? I'd be more than happy if I could accept your answer...

Comment: Replace the file `libz.1.dylib` (in /Applications/PostGIS Utilities/pgShapeLoader.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libz.1.dylib) by `libz.1.dylib` located in /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib or /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib